# A Modest Proposal: the [popularity-contest] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Over at [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/265/decryption-by-pattern-analysis), the OP doesn't want to use an objective winning criterion like code brevity, but instead wants to accept the highest-voted answer. To me, that smells like a [popularity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188/stack-overflow-code-golf/64252#64252) [contest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232861/fibonacci-code-golf/233228#233228).

Personally, those two examples above are reason enough for me to never post a popularity contest. However, if someone should, against their better judgement, feel that such a contest has value, a `[popularity-contest]` tag would suffice to caution serious coders to stay away. It'd be like Parental Advisory, except in this case it's not a content-free advisory. :-)

Comments welcome.

---

On a similar train of thought: should popularity-contest questions be "strongly encouraged" to be community-wiki'd?

Comment: whats the thinking behind making them `community-wiki`?

Comment: @vzn You have to remember that I wrote this post in the very early stages of this site's life, when popularity contests were not welcome on the site (since they are non-objective). I still personally dislike them, but the community seemed to have become more accepting in the years since.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For me, the novelty of a code golf site is seeing the novel ways people apply the features of languages I am interested in.  As a result of this, it is quite likely I will be upvoting answers which are interesting to me, rather than worrying about testing shorter solutions in languages in I might not be interested in (I am not *only* referring to GolfScript here.)  An accepted answer is only worth 1.5 upvotes, so if there are a lot of users like myself on the site, such solutions will consistently underperform in terms of rep gains, even if  so called *popularity contest* questions are made CW.  There's no point penalizing anyone for answering what some might consider an unclear question.  All puzzles are objective questions to a point.  We either need to decide that those questions with less strict acceptance criteria are off topic or accept them for what they are.

I suggest that it would be sufficient to emphasize the importance of *appropriately setting expectations* for acceptance criteria in the faq, and perhaps require the use of a set of (less condescending) acceptance criteria tags eg: strict, popular-vote, or whatever-i-feel-like

The ability for the community to upvote and downvote questions is a feature of the StackExchange platform, not a bug.  **Let's not try making it into something it's not.**  There's nothing stopping anyone from making a *great* code golf site with automated testing/automatic assigning of points to the shortest answer.  This isn't that site.

Comment: +1 Thank you for a more nuanced approach, of coming from a "let's be upfront about what to consider an accepted answer". The tags you suggest may be helpful too; then people can filter the tags that they're uninterested in.