# Can we do anything with the showcase?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The showcase is intended to, and was, a place to show and see new languages. In fact, it motivated me to learn ><>.

But now, it's pretty much dead AFAIK. New languages keep coming in, but they usually get only 3 or 4 upvotes, which indicates not many people are actually viewing it; Good, hard-worked answers are buried in rubbish short answers like the BCT one.

It is no longer working. Closing it is of course a solution, but aren't there positive choices?

I also want to mention the problem about the removal of the one-vote-at-a-time rule.

> *It'd be like removing the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) from a challenge: the answers would still work, but the goal they were aiming for is gone.* -- https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10660/87986

Several users (myself included) preferred to follow the old rules despite the current community consensus. That's more or less against the original purpose of the challenge.

> *It may not invalidate existing answers, but it will make their structure confusing to anyone reading the updated challenge, and new answers will look different.* -- https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10659/87986

And new answers will look different. Yes they do. For example, the recent [Integral answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208978/87986) has a 1 byte answer, then 12 bytes, then suddenly 37 bytes.

This is just boring.

So, I'm looking for ideas, agreements, disagreements, comments, anything that will help improving the showcase. It's a great resource.

Answer (score 3):

> Good, hard-worked answers are buried in rubbish short answers like the BCT one.

If you view the catalogue by the Active tab, you'll see that these good answers rise to the top.

> they usually get only 3 or 4 upvotes

It's still working, it's just that people are showcasing esolangs. Most people don't have an interest towards them in general; they prefer to see and vote on practical languages. Someone should probably showcase an obscure practical language here. :P

> the recent Integral answer have a 1 byte answer, then 12 bytes, then suddenly 37 bytes.
>
> This is just boring.

I think the removed rule is just awful. Users now tend to post answers that don't fully showcase their language. This ruins the original intent of the Language Showcase.

On the other hand, it allows people to decide what they should do to make their answers interesting. They can now do whatever they want to their answers. However, you can always downvote if you think an answer is bad.

Comment: How 'bout those new good answers that didn't yet get much attention?

Comment: "It's still working, it's just that people are showcasing esolangs." Hey, I'm HighlyRadioactive, not a newbie. It's just that no one cares about the new showcases at all.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Just wait and see.

Comment: "It's not uninteresting, people are just trying to convince users that their golfing language is really capable." Not that the Integral showcase is boring, but the current mechanism is. Really, this is no difference from putting some random snippets on some Esowiki page.

Comment: I waited for a long time and saw a downvote.

Comment: Your edited answer looks self-contradictory.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive How does my answer contradict itself?

Comment: "sers now tend to post answers that don't fully showcase their language" + "The recent Integral answer didn't make me feel motivated to learn Integral at all".

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive How about now?

Comment: I would argue that slowly showcasing your stuff when accumulating upvotes (and intention) is the intent of the challenge - "Users now tend to post answers that don't fully showcase their language" is the main problem I'm trying to point out in the first paragraph.

Comment: The rule removal leads to many, many, many answers like the Integral one.

Answer (score 1):

Challenges get old and inactive, it happens to all of them. The Showcase is a unique type of challenge, that has done surprisingly well, given the controversies it's faced.

> But now, it's pretty much dead AFAIK. New languages keep coming in, but they usually get only 3 or 4 upvotes, which indicates not many people are actually viewing it

As long as new answers are coming in, a challenge isn't dead. Those answers may not get many upvotes, but that shouldn't matter. If you want to showcase your language, do so, regardless of the score - especially now that the limit on snippet lengths has been removed.

Furthermore, for a challenge that is over 5 years old, for new answers to still be getting 3 or 4 upvotes is pretty impressive. Not everyone upvotes every answer they see. I personally will browse a challenge and can give out no upvotes, or upvotes on most answers; in short, you cannot tell how active a challenge is by answer votes.

> Good, hard-worked answers are buried in rubbish short answers like the BCT one

First of all, if you don't like an answer, downvote and move on. Second of all, if you think an answer is good and has been worked on hard, upvote it. That's all. The Showcase is constantly active, given that people are always adding new snippets to their answers, so any low-effort answers will get buried and forgotten about soon enough, while constantly maintained answers will always be fairly easily found.

> It is no longer working. Closing it is of course a solution, but aren't there positive choices?

Agree to disagree as to "it is no longer working". It constantly gets new answers and updates, so it seems to be working to me. You may not find new languages to learn there (I assume that's what you mean by "no longer working") but others will.

Closing it is *absolutely not* a solution. Take a look at the accepted answer to the [linked discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10657/66833). Four years ago, we agreed that closing it wasn't a good solution. We can have a second poll to see how people are feeling, but, given the Showcase's constant activity, I doubt there's much support for closing it.

> I also want to mention the problem about the removal of the one-vote-at-a-time rule.

Again, as the accepted answer the last time we had this discussion states, the Showcase is *not* like most challenges here. The unique [showcase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/showcase) tag, along with being a community wiki, and the notice at the top of the challenge body all state "This is not a normal challenge", and therefore, we cannot treat it like a normal challenge. This site may not be the best place for such a thread, but we have it, it's active and popular, and it currently isn't doing any harm.

> Several users (myself included) preferred to follow the old rules despite the current community consensus

Well then, you can self-impose the old rules upon your answers. But that isn't a reason to change anything about the challenge. When it was a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), there were issues raised about how some newer answers weren't getting enough upvotes to properly compete with older answers. If you wish to constrain yourself by the old rules, then you also have to accept the possible failings of those rules.

> And new answers will look different. Yes they do. For example, the recent Integral answer have a 1 byte answer, then 12 bytes, then suddenly 37 bytes.

This is perfectly within the rules of the challenge. You may not like it, and it may be confusing, but it's a perfectly valid answer. Furthermore, as the answers are community wiki, you are always welcome to edit in additional snippets to improve the answer.

> This is just boring

That is completely subjective, and what voting is for. If you think an answer (or challenge) is boring, I invite you to leave a downvote and (preferably) a comment explaining why you think the answer/challenge is boring. After that, as long as the answer/challenge is valid/on-topic/acceptable for the site, move on.

---

Overall, the Showcase isn't a perfect system. But it works as an effective way to demonstrate your language and its interesting features. You personally may not like particular answers, or even the challenge as a whole, but, again, that's what voting's for.

If you think that users aren't fully showcasing their languages, I encourage you to leave an upvote and a comment to show that you're interested in the language and you'd like them to continue showcasing it. Or, if you know of an interesting feature that hasn't been demonstrated, you can always edit it in yourself. Finally, if you think an answer is low-effort, or isn't a good example of the language, you can downvote, or post your own showcase of that language.

Comment: "Those answers may not get many upvotes, but that shouldn't matter." Well, if no one sees it, then it didn't demonstrate anything to anyone.

Comment: "It constantly gets new answers and updates, so it seems to be working to me." Say a C&R challenge constantly gets cop but no one cared to crack them. Is it working? No.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I always avoid downvotes (unless that answer is rubbish, like the Conway's Game of Life Tetris thing) because 1. that wastes my rep and 2. I want to encourage people