# Should “Showcase your language one vote at a time” be immediately unlocked until we decide what to do with it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopening

[Another meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/26997) is talking about making changes to the [popular](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) but currently locked challenge [Showcase of Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44680/26997) in response to the debates that have been happening about it [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10457/26997) and [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10636/26997) and in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

That [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/26997) is currently only 13 hours old. It does have a [high voted answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10657/26997) from Dennis, but he explicitly says:

> *These are my own, personal ideas*; they are not fleshed out, and feedback, improvements, and additional ideas are welcome

So obviously more time is needed to finalize things in that answer, or to wait for other answers and ideas.

My question here is simply, should we unlock the Showcase *immediately* until the results of [Making an exception for the "Showcase of Languages"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/26997) are clear, i.e. until we decide precisely what to do with it?

This is a simpler question than "what should we do with the Showcase". All I'm asking here is:

1. Should the Showcase be unlocked *immediately* and put back to normal until we decide what to do with it, or
2. Should it be kept locked until we decide what to do with it.

No other options.

Note that:

- The Showcase was locked in direct denial of what the community wanted in [Proposal to lock the Language Showcase as historically significant](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10457/26997). The top 4 answers there are against locking the showcase.
- The Showcase was kept locked despite the popular answer to [Should "Showcase your language one vote at a time" be unlocked and reopened?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10636/should-showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time-be-unlocked-and-reopened) saying it should be unlocked.
- The [new meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/26997) should be viewed as a *new* proposal about changing the Showcase. It is not our policy to lock or change challenges simply because a meta post about them exists. We wait until that meta post is finalized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

What's the huge hurry? It's been *13 hours* since [Dennis's meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/20260). That not's even be long enough to sandbox a challenge. Many users don't check meta that often. Some even sleep. The point is to discuss. Just wait.

Besides, re-opening with no changes corresponds to [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10659/20260), which is at +4/-6 as of this writing.

Frankly, I find this request ridiculous. "*Immediately*" is at best the many hours this new meta takes to gather consensus. I can't see how this is supposed to speed up the process.

Comment: We can discuss it while open. The decision to lock was not what the community ever wanted. We don't lock challenges just because meta posts about them exist.

Comment: This is not meant to speed up the process, nor slow it down. This is to fix the mistake of locking in the first place that the community never agreed to.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies What you're describing seems what you're asking for in your previous post "Should “Showcase your language one vote at a time” be unlocked and reopened?" I have no idea what you could mean by "immediately" if not asking to speed up the process.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying it should be unlocked and put back to normal as that post indicates. There was never a rational to lock in the first place so there is no "process" being changed here, only a reversal of the mistaken decision to lock the challenge. Once Dennis' current meta post has time to be finalized, go ahead and make the changes it suggests.

Comment: I mean, do you really think it ever should have been locked despite any majority community approval for that?

Answer (score -7):

## Yes

We should unlock the [Showcase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time) *immediately* until [Making an exception for the "Showcase of Languages"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/26997) has more time to accrue answers and comments, until we can agree its decision is final.

Remember:

- There [was](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10459/26997) [never](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10467/26997) [a](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10492/26997) [concensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10470/26997) [to](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10637/26997) lock the Showcase in the first place. Doing it was a mistake.
- There is no policy that we lock challenges just because a [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10656/26997) exists about them.

Comment: You do realise that locking it was a deliberately *understated* action taken in recognition of the attention that the thread has received over its lifetime? If it hadn't been for that, it could have been deleted instead. You're seriously overreacting.

Comment: I get that it was suggested to be locked instead of deleted because of its popularity, but there was never majority community support for either of those options, so why did one of them happen?

Comment: Because, as I commented on an answer to your earlier question, community consensus is necessary to break the rules, not to enforce them.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what that means. Who makes or breaks or enforces or does anything with the rules if not the community as a whole? Mods can be arbiters, but in this instance there was no indication that a majority of the community wanted the Showcase locked.

Comment: [Read the whole thing in context](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10653/194)