# Code challenge &

Tags: discussion, code-challenge

I see new users treat "code-challenge" as "it's hard to solve, but once done you win", but "code-challenge" here seems to mean "you need to optimize, but it's hard to put such an scoring way in one class" (Source: with an objective winning criterion not covered by other scoring tags).

1) How to make new user just see what CC mean?

2) What do "hard to solve but win when solved" go?

[Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5594/)

Comment: [tag:code-challenge] is simply the tag where the winning criterion is not covered by other tags (such as [tag:code-golf])

Comment: By reading the [tag info page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-challenge/info)?

Comment: I think you reading something don't make others know it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) How to make new user just see what CC mean?

There is a proverb in English: *you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink*. [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) already has a tag summary which says what it means: there is no way of forcing a new user to read it, to click through for a more detailed explanation, or to think about whether it applies to their case. Perhaps the summary could be improved: if you think so, you can propose new wording for it.

> 2) What do "hard to solve but win when solved" go?

In most cases, a different website. They break the Q&A model even more than most of our questions. Although the Puzzling site changed its scope to include that kind of question, PPCG has not.

The main exception is [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle), but that has a very narrow definition, and should ideally have a secondary criterion to pick the best out of multiple solutions.