# Why is a language identification challenge off-topic in CGCC?

Tags: discussion, scope

## NOTE:

not dupe of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/are-pure-programming-puzzles-on-topic?noredirect=1&lq=1) because all are different answers.

#### Back to start

Some questions like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237300/can-someone-tell-me-what-if-anything-this-says-using-golf-coding) are obviously off-topic, but some what sees on-topic but not on this site (CGCC)?

Like:

“

## What programming language is?

```
+[.+]
```

Prints ascii table. but what programming language is?

”

Is off-topic in CGCC but why?

### Edit:

not including [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

Comment: For the specific example you provided, there's a [tag:cops-and-robbers] challenge [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54807/the-programming-language-quiz).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are pure programming puzzles on topic?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/are-pure-programming-puzzles-on-topic)

Comment: @user no. it doesn't answer me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it does not have a [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8135/56656).

As phrased the shown challenge has a single correct answer. We require challenges with multiple correct answers which can be ranked, so that you are encouraged to improve on your answer.

As such this is either regular Q&A and as it says in [our tour page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour):

> We are not a Q&A site.

Or more likely it's a puzzle.  It's not a *programming puzzle*, which is a jargon term here, but it's a puzzle about programming.  If it's a puzzle you will probably actually have better luck on the [puzzling stack-exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), where I believe it would be on topic.  But of course you should check their rules first.

Lastly I should mention that the sole exception to this rule is [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips).  Which is a form of Q&A which we occasionally do.  But this is not [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) it's a different thing.