# Is "Most Elegant" objective

Tags: discussion, policy, popularity-contest, tips

This comes up in popularity contests all the time. Most elegant as a scoring criteria (or similar). Is a popularity contest objective in and of itself by saying that most votes wins? It is very objective to compare two numbers. How those numbers were created may not be objective. What is the community consesus on this. This is **NOT** a dupe of [What makes winning criteria "objective"?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/what-makes-winning-criteria-objective) as I am specifically interested in popularity contests not all other winning criteria. What makes a good popularity contest question better than a bad one.

Comment: I think this may be a dupe of http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8084/8478 though? Basically, the community isn't really sure what to do about them because as you say the *voting criteria* are indeed subjective.

Comment: @MartinEnder ok thanks! That answered my question. I will vote to close my own question as a dupe!